# How to obtain an expression of the complexity of the period-finding algorithm with respect to the period length?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, textbook-and-exercises, period-finding-algorithm

**Intro**. Nielsen and Chuang in *Quantum computation and quantum information* on section 5.4.1 state that the period-finding algorithm has a runtime of $U + O(L^2)$ operations where $L$ is the size of the register used to store the number that's the length of the period.

**My task, my objective**. For all of my periodic functions of interest I know an upper bound for the length of the period, but sometimes the period is much shorter than the upper bound I can get.  So I'm interested in getting an expression of the complexity of the period-finding algorithm with respect to the period length.

**My trouble**. So far I have not found any connection at all between $r$, the period-length, and the time it will take for the algorithm to finish.  So if you can begin with pointing me in this direction, this might be a good start and I might just be able to take it from there.  (This isn't homework, but I'm okay with assuming so.  Thank you!)